# Не могу понять как выводить возраст из inputa в текст если возраст в середине текста

Tags: javascript, html

Не могу понять как выводить возраст из inputa в текст если возраст в середине текста
Кода нет, нужно что то вроде этого
result.innerHTML = `В твоём имени символов`;

Comment: Код в студию...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы отобразить возраст, введенный в поле ввода в тексте на HTML-странице, вы можете использовать JavaScript, чтобы получить значение поля ввода и вставить его в текст. Вот простой пример:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function displayAge() {
        var age = document.getElementById("ageInput").value;
        document.getElementById("ageDisplay").innerHTML = age;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label for="ageInput">Enter your age:</label>
    <input type="text" id="ageInput">
    <button onclick="displayAge()">Display Age</button>
    <p>Your age is: <span id="ageDisplay"></span></p>
  </body>
</html>
```